# List of classes with events in designer

Tags: c#, events, list, propertygrid

I'm writing a wrapper for OPC communication to a controller, and I have created a component like follows;

```
public class OPCGroup : Component
{
    (snipped)

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public List<OPCItem> Items
    {
        get { return mItems; }
        set { mItems = value; }
    }

}
```

Each item in the Items list above looks like this

```
public class OPCItem : MarshalByRefObject, IDisposable
{
    private String mName;

    private String mTag;

    private object mValue;

    public String Name
    {
        get { return mName; }
        set { mName = value; }
    }

    public String Tag
    {
        get { return mTag; }
        set { mTag = value; }
    }

    public object Value
    {
        get { return mValue; }
        set { Change(value, true); }
    }

    public event OPCItemEvent Changed;
}
```

Now the problem is that the Changed event of the OPCItem is not changeable in design time, i can add events to the items in run time using

```
opcGroup1.Items[0].Changed += new OPCItemEvent(Item0Changed);
```

However, i would like to be able to bind the events in design time instead as it is easier.

I have tried creating the events manually using the IEventBindingService  in a custom UITypeEditor as follows

```
        IEventBindingService eventBindingService = provider.GetService(typeof(IEventBindingService)) as IEventBindingService;


        EventDescriptorCollection edc = TypeDescriptor.GetEvents(Group.Items[0]);

        EventDescriptor Event = edc.Find("Changed", false);

        PropertyDescriptor pd = eventBindingService.GetEventProperty(Event);

        pd.SetValue(Group.Items[0], Group.Items[0].Name + "Changed");
```

But then I get the error

> Events cannot be set on the object passed to the event binding service because a site associated with the object could not be located

So then i implemented the IComponent interface in the OPCItem class to get the Site property, but now the collection items are shown on the designer.

Any advice on how to approach this problem?